# How to enable Altium Designer to check missing connection?

Tags: altium

I purposely removed the connection on R306, but that doesn't trigger an error.  How can I enable this type of check on Altium Designer?  From project option, I pretty much enabled all checks. What am I missing?  Thanks. [image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Nets with one pin should do the trick.

Be sure the wire connected to the top of R306 doesn't have a residual net name of V_IN for this test.

Comment: I also have the wire completely removed.  Still no errors.  Thanks.